# Passport.js google strategy works fine on localhost, but doesn't work in production, the user is never attached to the session

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I need help. I am building a web app where users can login with Google. I use Passport.js, Node and Express, React on the front end. On localhost everything works fine, session is set and user gets authorized. I host my app on Cyclic, and it doesn't work there. The session is set, but there is no user attached, therefore passport deserializeUser() function never gets called. I tried using express-session, and cookie-session with the same result. Any suggestions?
Here is my server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

const passport = require("passport");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const expressSession = require('express-session')
//const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const session = {
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true ,
    saveUninitialized: true ,
    cookie: {
     maxAge: 60*60*1000, 
     sameSite: 'none',
      httpOnly: false
    }
}

  app.set('trust proxy', 1) 
const HTTP_PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    cors(
    {origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true
}
)
);

app.use(expressSession(session));
//app.use(cookieSession(session));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require("./models/User");
require("./services/google-facebook-auth");
require("./services/email-auth");
require("./services/updatePassword");

require("./routes/authRoutes")(app);
require("./routes/updatePassword")(app);
mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://wefriiends-backup:password@cluster0.wir50id.mongodb.net/authorization?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    { 
        useNewUrlParser: true, 
        useUnifiedTopology: true 
    }
);
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function() {
    console.log("Connection Successful!");
    app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => {
        console.log("API listening on: " + HTTP_PORT);
    });
   
});
```

And here is my gogle-startegy:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = mongoose.model("users");

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_AUTH_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "myserver/api/auth/google/callback",
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {  
       
        const userFound = await User.findOne({
            $or: [{
                    'userId': profile.emails[0].value
                  }, {
                    'googleId': profile.id
            }]});
        if (userFound) {           
            done(null, userFound);
        } else {            
            const userToSave = new User({
                userId: profile.emails[0].value,
                googleId: profile.id,
                status: "Active",
                confirmationCode: "code" + profile.id
            });
            const user = await userToSave.save();
            done (null, user)
        }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
      done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  User.findById(user._id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, already wasted lots of time debugging. Can you please share if you find a solution? Tnx